# Make play json reads serialisable

Tags: json, serialization, apache-spark, playframework-2.0, typeclass

Because I'm working with spark, and because I think play json lib is convenient I try to parse json with this lib in spark.

I would like to have a generic RDD transform like

```
def parse[T: Reads](source : RDD[String]) = RDD[T] {
  source.map(s => Json.parse(s).validate[T] ).collect{
    case JsSuccess(event,_) => event
  }
}
```

But as you see the implicit Reads is give to the worker and it's not serializable.

I have try to wrap the Reads with

`val serializableReads = () => implicity[Reads]`

( because fn are by default serializable )

Or to wrap Reads in a class extending serializable.

But I'm not able to make it work.
Any one know if it's possible to do without asking to play dev to make there classes serializable?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same, no way at moment.
We end up with Dataframe to manage json. But if you need some more specific I suggest json4s-jackson that should be the internal library of spark to handle json, so it should be serializable.

Comment: Play json use jackson ;) for now I directly give my type in the worker, it's less modulable but is a lot cleaner than dataframe